# .htaccess on IIS. Helicon Ape Manager does not convert htaccess to web config

Tags: htaccess, apache, webserver, iis

I want to use PHP and .htaccess on my IIS server. I already know that the .htaccess is not supported by IIS. I know that the .htaccess need to convert to the web config. I want to try with Helicon App Manager do this.

I installed the trial version before buying, but I'm not sure if it works. If I understood correctly: by launching the program see a text editor with the main config or .htaccess particular site and creating .htaccess entries should be after saving convert to web config. But I do not see any changes. .htaccess Is changing but not config. NTFS permissions are set with full privileges for iis user. Checked for license free hand, checked the main httpd.

Did I do something wrong, or do not understand something?

Comment: I got message from support:
"Helicon Ape does not convert .htaccess into web.config, instead it implements most of Apache features itself. It can load and interpret .htaccess files, executing instructions in them, so to the developer it looks much like running Apache server. Some .htaccess instructions may indeed be converted into web.config, others not, but it is not what Ape does. Please send your .htaccess file to support for analysis."